# Writing your own Jquery function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to write a function so that I can execute commands like so:

```
$("#Button").glow();
```

What do I have to override, or how do I have to structure the "glow" function so that I can call it the way I do above?

Comment: read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). Read documentation. Do and try something. Like for example:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.glow = function(options) {  
        return this.each(function() {     
            // TODO: do something for each element that matched your selector
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 9):

You must declare a jQuery function like as:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {

  // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

};
```

and after that

```
$("#Button").myPlugin();
```

read here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 7):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.glow = function() {
       return this.each(function() { //<--optionally, parameters here
           // your logic here
           // `this` at this point refers to the DOM element
       });
    }
})(jQuery); //<-- Closure to allow using $ where $ is not jQuery any more
```

`return` in `return this.each(..)` enables chaining jQuery plugins, so that you can use:

```
$("selector").glow().anothermethod();
//If return was omitted, the previous line would throw an error
```

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

all you need to know about making you're own plugin.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.glow = function() {

    //your selected element is 'this'
    this. ...//do your magic

  };
})( jQuery );
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
$('#element').glow();
```

For complete info, check this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.glow = function () {
  //Do Stuff
}
```